# need to send email notification to user on a java project

Tags: java, email

So I'm working on a class (all the students in the class) project (I won't have control of the server, installation stuff etc.. is there any way of sending an email without knowing about the system the project is going to be deployed? (I'm not going to be involved on that process, so is not like I can run any scripts on the server)
We are working on Java and we have the Spring framework to work with.
Can I use a precompiled jar? (I heard something about that not to sure)

I've being trying to get samples using javamail, but I can't test it on my computer.. I have localhost enabled and running, but it doesn't work, and I can't find a tutorial that takes me trough all the steps of setting up the computer and getting the code to work [im on a mac])

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well if you want to test mail functionality using java mail you can use any of the email provider like `gmail` etc as they provide SMTP mail faility.

make sure you use them only for testing purpose as using bulk mail or sending mails exceeding your quota can disable your account for the time.

Do somethng like

```
String host = "smtp.gmail.com";
 String from = "username";
 String pass = "password";
Propertindexes props = System.getPropertindexes();
props.put("maindexl.smtp.starttls.enable", "true"); 
props.put("maindexl.smtp.host", host);
props.put("maindexl.smtp.user", from);
props.put("maindexl.smtp.password", pass);
props.put("maindexl.smtp.port", "587");
props.put("maindexl.smtp.auth", "true");

String[] to = {"to@gmaindexl.com"}; 

Sessindexon sessindexon = Sessindexon.getDefaultindexnstance(props, null);
MindexmeMessage message = new MindexmeMessage(sessindexon);
message.setFrom(new indexnternetAddress(from));

indexnternetAddress[] toAddress = new indexnternetAddress[to.length];


for( int index=0; index < to.length; index++ ) { 
    toAddress[index] = new indexnternetAddress(to[index]);
}
System.out.prindexntln(Message.RecindexpindexentType.TO);

for( int index=0; index < toAddress.length; index++) { 
    message.addRecindexpindexent(Message.RecindexpindexentType.TO, toAddress[index]);
}
message.setSubject("hello Maindexl");
message.setText("Hello");
Transport transport = sessindexon.getTransport("smtp");
transport.connect(host, from, pass);
transport.sendMessage(message, message.getAllRecindexpindexents());
transport.close();
```

Though i have not tested the code but it should wrok

Comment: Yahoo only includes SMTP with paid Yahoo Mail Plus accounts.

Comment: @Paul i long time ago tried with gmail so though yahoo might also work :) anyways just removed yahoo to avoid misconception

Answer (score 0):

You don't need an email server to be sending out emails.

Have you checked out how Apache Commons Email can help you on this?

http://commons.apache.org/email/

You can use your own GMAIL account to send out such emails for non critical cases. :D

Answer (score 0):

Have you spoken to your instructor about this?  It seem odd you won't know the deployment environment yet have to send mail through it.  Nevertheless, there are some solutions that are easier than setting up your own mail server (which your ISP may disapprove of), and may work on your target environment depending on how the network is connected (firewall, e.g.):

1. Use an external service like GMail.  [Here's an example](http://www.mkyong.com/java/javamail-api-sending-email-via-gmail-smtp-example/) of sending mail through GMail using JavaMail.
2. Use your ISP's mail server.  The [JavaMail API](http://javamail.kenai.com/nonav/javadocs/index.html) has a straightforward example, and if you [download the whole package](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/index-138643.html) there are many examples (including using other webmail providers like Windows Live Mail (aka Hotmail) ).  Don't forget to look at [the FAQ](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html).
3. If you find you need to include your own mail server, Rose India has a [JavaMail overview](http://www.roseindia.net/javamail/) which includes that step.  They reference [Apache James](http://james.apache.org/), an enterprise-grade mail server, which might be a bit much for what you need.

I'd recommend taking this up with your instructor first...it may save you a lot of headaches.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static int enviarCorreo(int puerto,String serverPrograma, String mailPrograma, String passMailPrograma, String info, String subject, String emailDestinatario, String ubicacionAdjunto1, String ubicacionAdjunto2, String nomAdjunto1, String nomAdjunto2) {
            int err=0;

             boolean conArchAdjunto1=true;
             boolean conArchAdjunto2=true;
            if(ubicacionAdjunto1.equals("")){
                conArchAdjunto1=false;
            }
            if(ubicacionAdjunto2.equals("")){
                conArchAdjunto2=false;
            }


            try {
                // obtaining the session, this configuration is for
                // a gmail account
                Properties props = new Properties();
                props.put("mail.smtp.host", serverPrograma);
                props.setProperty("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
                props.setProperty("mail.smtp.port", puerto);//587
                props.setProperty("mail.smtp.user", mailPrograma);
                props.setProperty("mail.smtp.auth", "true");

                Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);
                // session.setDebug(true);

                // composing the text
                BodyPart texto = new MimeBodyPart();
                texto.setText(info);

                // multipart for text and images
                MimeMultipart multiParte = new MimeMultipart();

                // composing the att

                if (conArchAdjunto1) {
                    BodyPart adjunto1 = new MimeBodyPart();
                    adjunto1.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(new FileDataSource(ubicacionAdjunto1)));
                    adjunto1.setFileName(nomAdjunto1);
                    multiParte.addBodyPart(adjunto1);
                }
                if (conArchAdjunto2) {
                    BodyPart adjunto2 = new MimeBodyPart();
                    adjunto2.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(new FileDataSource(ubicacionAdjunto2)));
                    adjunto2.setFileName(nomAdjunto2);
                    multiParte.addBodyPart(adjunto2);
                }
                multiParte.addBodyPart(texto);

                // composing mail, to, from, subject and
                // content.
                MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
                message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(mailPrograma));

                message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(
                        emailDestinatario));
                message.setSubject(subject);
                message.setContent(multiParte);


                message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.BCC,
                        new InternetAddress(mailPrograma));
                message.setSubject(subject);
                message.setContent(multiParte);

                // Se envia el correo.
                Transport t = session.getTransport("smtp");
                t.connect(mailPrograma, passMailPrograma);
                t.sendMessage(message, message.getAllRecipients());
                t.close();
                log.info("Clase EnviarMail, metodo enviarCorreo: Mail sended");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                err=-1;
                log.error("Clase EnviarMail, metodo enviarCorreo: " +e.getMessage());
            }
            return err;
        }
```

I use this code and works perfect, remember to import the **javax.mail** and another tip is that some properties like mailPrograma (the mail you want to send the email) could be configured in a .properties with the pass and some redundant code which yo wanna change later...